# SQL Server index creation in 2012 and 2016

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

Below index script fails in SQL Server 2012:

```
CREATE TABLE #ContextDetailTaskTable  
(
    ContextDetailID bigint not null,
    index #ContextDetailTaskTableIndex clustered (ContextDetailID)
)
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'index'. If this is intended as a part of a table hint, A WITH keyword and parenthesis are now required. See SQL Server Books Online for proper syntax.

Whereas the same is working in SQL Server 2016.

I have set the transaction isolation level to snapshot hence create index cannot work https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/531747/error-3964-on-create-index-on-temporary-table-under-snapshot-isolation-level

We added a dummy column and added identity into it. Hope this does not impact the performance?

Workaround in SQL Server 2012:

```
CREATE TABLE #ContextIDTable  
(
     ContextDetailID bigint NOT NULL,
     ID1 INT NOT NULL identity(1,1),

     CONSTRAINT PK_#ContextIDTable 
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ContextDetailID, ID1)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this code instead:

```
CREATE TABLE #ContextDetailTaskTable  
(
    ContextDetailID BIGINT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_ContextDetailTaskTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
)
```

Define a **constraint** and make it the clustered primary key. That will automatically create an index behind the scenes.

This should work just fine in any version of SQL Server 2005 and newer.

If you look at the [Microsoft documentation on `CREATE TABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql), you'll see that the `index .....` syntax you're using applies to SQL Server **2014** and newer only.

Comment: @MartinSmith: that is true - I was *guessing* from the way the question was asked that this would be the case - but it's not clear, I agree. My approach here will of course **only work** if that `ID` is in fact the primary key and therefore unique

Comment: --2016
CREATE TABLE #ContextIDTable  
(
  ContextDetailID bigint NOT NULL,
  index #ContextDetailTableIndex clustered (ContextDetailID)
)
--2012
CREATE TABLE #WFEngineQueueCompleteOrphanInstanceTable  
   (
    ID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_#WFEngineQueueCompleteOrphanInstanceTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID))
We are getting primarky error of some of temp tables, is there a workaround to create index without primary key.

Comment: @omkar: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Sure Sorry for that.